# Error in SQL query in mapbasic

Tags: sql, mapbasic

I am writing below SQL query in mapbasic to insert columns from two tables `t1` and `t2` into table `Sites` but error is occuring "Variable or field t2.CELLID not defined"

`Table Sites (Source integer, N integer, LAT float, LONG float)
Select t1.CELLID, t2.CELLID, t2.LATITUDE, t2.LONGITUDE from t1 left join t2 on t1.CELLID=t2.CELLID where t1.obj within zone into Sites`

Can anyone tell me how to rectify it?

Comment: Unfortunately MapBasic only allows inner joins so you will not be able to perform a left, right, or full join directly like that though there are workarounds involving more steps. Also, it's not clear what `zone` relates to in the query... is that an object variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Table Sites (Source integer, N integer, LAT float, LONG float)

```
Select t1.CELLID "CellID1", t2.CELLID "CellID2", t2.LATITUDE, t2.LONGITUDE 
  From t1, t2 
  Where t1.CELLID = t2.CELLID 
  And t1.obj within zone 
  into __TO__INSERT
Insert Into Sites
   Select CellID1, CellID2, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE
   From __TO__INSERT
```

But notice that you will only insert the records where there is a match between the CellIDs in the two tables. As @Tom_Bacon mentioned, MapInfo SQL doesn't support outer joins.